# Example about Kronecker product and inverse properties

Tags: matrices, inverse, kronecker-product

If $A\otimes B$ where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product, is invertible, then $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily invertible. I need an example

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

See properties 4. $A\otimes B$ is invertible if and only if $A$ and $B$ are invertible.